# Handling excel spreadsheets with Cucumber Scenario Outline

Tags: java, excel, selenium, cucumber, qaf

I am trying to see, if possible, to have a more elegant way to handle calling nTh numbers from a Cucumber Scenario Outline that correlates to an excel spreadsheet row(nth).

Currently I am using iteration numbers to define the row # of the excel spread sheet to pull the data from.  I wanted to see if it was possible to use cucumber with excel in a more elegant way than the below example with the scenario outline.

Some background:

- Each iteration needs to be its own scenario.  Hence why I'm not using a
  simple for loop with row.count.
- I am fully aware of scenario outline as a way to do data tables but my company wants to see a POF that we can integrate large data sets through excel.
- Current setup works for small data sets but when we get into the large excel spreadsheets I do not want to type out nth numbers on the outline

Cucumber code:

```
Feature: User is using an excel spreadsheet with cucumber driving it

  Scenario Outline: Data Driven with excel and data sets

   When I am on the amps mainscreen
    Then I input username and passwords with excel row"<row_index>" dataset

    Examples:
    | row_index  |
    | 1          |
    | 2          |
    | 3          |
    | 4          |
```

Step File:

```
//Excel Steps
@When("^I am on the amps mainscreen$")
public void i_am_on_the_amps_mainscreen()  {
    System.out.println("Im loading");
}
//Excel Steps
@Then("^I input username and passwords with excel row\"([^\"]*)\" dataset$")
public void i_input_username_and_passwords_with_excel_row_dataset(int rownum)    throws IOException {
    login.readExcel(rownum);
}
```

Actual Code:

```
 public void readExcel (int row) throws IOException{

    File src=new File("src/test/resources/username.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook srcBook= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sourceSheet = srcBook.getSheetAt(0);

    XSSFRow sourceRow = sourceSheet.getRow(row);
    XSSFCell username=sourceRow.getCell(0);
    XSSFCell password=sourceRow.getCell(1);
    String userExcel = username.getStringCellValue();
    String pwExcel = password.getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println("The username is" +userExcel);
    System.out.println("The password is" +pwExcel);
    log.info("The username on " +row + " is: "+userExcel);
    log.info("The password on "+row+ " is: "+pwExcel);
    driver.findElement(txtbox_username).sendKeys(userExcel);
    driver.findElement(txtbox_password).sendKeys(pwExcel);
    driver.findElement(btn_logon).click();

}
```

Comment: That's an anti-pattern. If you can't read it, then it's not helpful.

Comment: I understand, its more of a Proof of concept then actual application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) with [gherkin factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.9/gherkin_client.html#benefits-of-using-qaf-gherkin-scenario-factory). It supports test data provided outside feature file for example excel, xml, json, csv, or database. you can provide datafile for examples like:

> Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.xls'}

Here is the [example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/releases/download/2.1.9-RC2/QAFGherkin.zip) you can check.